# export a base64-encrypted jpg

Tags: r, base64, jpeg

I want to export a base64-encrypted jpg.

Here is my approach:

1) Select cell in the table with the Base64 code

2) Decrypt code with "base64_decode"

3) Save the file as a .jpg file

When decrypting, the following error message appears

```
Error in rawToChar(base64_decode(testbody)) : 
  embedded nul in string:
```

that's what my code looks like:

```
testbody = Boden$body[5]
test = rawToChar(base64_decode(testbody))
```

This is the content of testbody:

```
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
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just trying to save the picture somewhere, you can do this

```
raw <- base64enc::base64decode(testbody)
writeBin(raw, "foo.jpg")
```

First, turn the base64 data into bytes, then just write those bytes to a file. If you want to work with the data in R first, you can read them as JPEG images as well

```
pic <- jpeg::readJPEG(raw)
plot(1:2, type="n")
rasterImage(pic, 1, 1, 2, 2)
jpeg::writeJPEG(pic, "pic.jpg")
```